# Batch compare subfolder

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory

I have two folders with a lot of subfolders. I am not interested in the contents of the subfolders, but I would like to compare the subfolders of the two folders. I would like to have a list of subfolder names which only exist in one of the two main folders, so subfolders which are in both main folders are correct.
I tried something of the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
for %%i in ("test1\*") do if not exist "test2\%%~nxi" echo(%%~i)
pause
```

but this only works (sort of) if I was interested in files and not subfolder names. It probably is a quick fix, but unfortunately I'm not well-versed in scripting.

Comment: `for /D %%i in ("test1\*") do if not exist "test2\%%~nxi\" echo(%%~i`

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response, it works!

Comment: Helps to read the help file for the command you are trying to use.

Comment: You need to do the same command line twice (using `for /D` rather than `for`), once with `test1` and `test2` exchanged, to achieve a complete list...